# Sql into php syntax error

Tags: php, sql

So, I have this code that returns into a syntax error. Can you please help me figure out what the problem is?

```
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tablename (column) 
VALUES('".$php_var."') WHERE cat = $php_var2") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: you should provide more of your code. What is $php_var and $php_var2.
What do you want as a result ? What is the table's structure ?

Comment: What error specifically?

Comment: $php_var is an integer and the column value is also an integer. The error says that is a sintax error near WHERE cat = $php_var2

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP - an `insert` statement just doesn't have a `where` clause. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Please, read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: you can only use a `where` clause in and INSERT when doing and [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Comment: Your code is not only prone to SQL injection, it also uses deprecated methods. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Answer (score 2):

You cant use `WHERE` clause with `INSERT`. If you want to insert then the query will be -

```
"INSERT INTO tablename (column) VALUES('".$php_var."')"
```

Or if it is update then -

```
"UPDATE tablename SET column = '".$php_var."' WHERE cat = '" . $php_var2 . "'"
```

Try to avoid `mysql`. Use `mysqli` or `PDO`

Comment: b0s3 is correct. 
@details You are inserting a new row. are you want to update any data.

Comment: ...or [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) which does use a `where` clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do INSERT with WHERE clause unless it's WHERE NOT EXISTS, so just do:

```
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tablename (column) VALUES('$php_var')");
```

Maybe you needed to do UPDATE

```
$query = mysql_query("UPDATE tablename SET column='$php_var' WHERE cat = '$php_var2' ");
```

Answer (score 0):

`INSERT INTO` syntax can't accept a `WHERE`.
The good syntax is:

```
INSERT INTO table_name 
VALUES(...);
```

Or, if you prefer not to insert in all the table columns:

```
INSERT INTO table_name(column_name1, column_name2, ...) 
VALUES(column1_value, column2_value, ...);
```

---

As a side note, in your request you don't insert your PHP variable, but some text.